# How to generate an XML document in iOS using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xml, nsxmldocument

I want to generate an XML document in iOS. My primary goal is to generate it using inbuilt classes/libraries. I researched a lot and I found that NSXMLElement, NSXMLDocument etc are used to generate XML in OS X but not in iOS (correct me if I'm wrong about this). I found some of the third party libraries like GDataXML, APXML etc which generates the XMLDocument as per my needs. But, I'm trying hard to achieve the same using inbuilt classes (if any). BTW, I do not want the strings to be appended manually to create XML.

I'm not expecting a complete code which does the generation. Any help/suggestion on any inbuilt classes would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://skjolber.github.io/xswi/), may it help @nagarjuna.

Answer (score 1):

You're right -- you need to look for a 3rd party solution for XML writing in iOS.  For parsing, there is `NSXMLParser`.

Comment: Mustache (https://github.com/groue/GRMustache) is very beautiful 3rd party solution for generate xml from template (template can also be use from android).

Comment: Yeah it looks good and I think I've to finally rely on third party solution. I don't know why apple has not created one.